# Suspend function until another is called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, twilio

I have a function in node that is responsible for signing up a new user and saving the user object to the database. However this should only happens when the user requests an SMS verification code and then inputs the correct code sent. This is a model of my current flow:

```
signUp(userData){
  sendVerificationCode()

  // after verifyCode() is called in the future and code is valid
  saveUserData()
}

sendVerificationCode(){
 // send a request to twilio which then sends an SMS to the user
}

verifyCode(){ 
 // send a request to twilio with the code and the response 
 // is whether the code is valid
}
```

`signUp` is the first function that is called, it should then call the `sendVerificationCode` function and then in the future `verifyCode` will be called and only then should `signUp` continue and save the user data. How can I do this? It seems like I need to pause a function until another function is called.

Comment: Is this in a node.js HTTP server? Which functions are async? If it's a webserver, is there more than on web process running? The answer depends heavily on some of these questions (and probably more).

Comment: @jbielick None of the functions are currently async. I only added the tag because I figured maybe some of them should be async to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are easier ways to do this than suspending execution of a function. I understand what you'd like to do and there are ways to write this asynchronously that allow you do what you want.

Here's a very simple example of doing something like what you're describing in a single process. It assumes that `signUp` will be invoked when a user tries to sign up. Then `sendVerificationCode` is called, which I presume triggers Twilio to send the user a code. The `userData` is stored in-memory (you can also use a database for this) in `database.pendingUsers`. We can key our pending users by the phone number they gave to sign up. The `signUp` function ends here.

I assume the next step is for the user to enter the code as input to our program somehow. When the user submits the code back to our script (that part is up to you—no details were provided about http, command-line, or otherwise) we can invoke `verifyCode`. When `verifyCode` is called, we'll need the phone number (I can't offer a suggestion on how to get this without knowing how a user interacts with this code). We can verify the code we're given with Twilio and if it is valid, take the user details from `pendingUsers` and persist it to `users`. You might be using a database for this, in which case your code will look different, but the logic is similar.

Here's the sample code:

```
const database = {
  pendingUsers: {},
  users: {},
};

signUp(userData){
  database.pendingUsers[userData.phone] = userData;
  sendVerificationCode(userData.phone);
}

sendVerificationCode(phone) {
  // send a request to twilio which then sends an SMS to the user
}

verifyCode(message) {
  // you need to get a hold of the phone number this verification code is for
  const phone = message.from;

  // send a request to twilio with the code and the response 
  // is whether the code is valid

  const verified = ...; // verify code

  if (!verified) {
    return false;
  }

  const userData = database.pendingUsers[phone];

  if (userData) {
    // remove from pending
    delete database.pendingUsers[phone];
    // save user
    database.users.push(userData);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use another approximation for this use case. In a previous step, the client asks for an SMS code, at this moment the API call ends.

In a second moment, the client sends the information of the code and the user information, you verify the code, and, if it correct, you save the user information on the database.

In the suppose that you're using NodeJS 8, you can declare verifyCode() as an asynchronous function and use `await verifyCode()` to wait for the response.

For example:

```
// The first request of the client 
verificationCodeRequest(userData){
   sendVerificationCode()
}

signUp(userData){
   try {
     response = await verifyCode();  
     // Maybe, you need another validation
     if (isCodeCorrect) { 
        writeToDB(userData);
     } else {
       error();
     }
   } catch (err) {
     error();
   }


sendVerificationCode(){
 // send a request to twilio which then sends an SMS to the user
}

async verifyCode(){ 
 // send a request to twilio with the code and the response 
 // is whether the code is valid
}
```

I hope that I understood your question and sorry for my English, I'm working on it.